# An inequality problem..

Tags: inequality

Given any $a_{ij}, b_{ij}$ real numbers, for $i,j=1\ldots n$. How can I show that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}\Big)^2 \leq \Big( \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \Big)\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}^2 \Big) ? $$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy Schwarz:

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^na^2_{ik}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb^2_{kj}\right).$$

Notice $a_{ik}$ has the $i$ index and $b_{kj}$ has the $j$ index. So

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^na^2_{ik}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb^2_{kj}\right)=\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^na^2_{ik}\right)\right]\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb^2_{kj}\right)\right],$$

and now relable indices.